# How to add to a list for a Docker yaml extension

Tags: docker-compose

Is there a way with docker-compose to allow extension fields to add fields to a list?

I've tried a whole bunch of combinations, but haven't seen if there's a way to do this

What I want to do is have a set list of volumes (in a list) and then a few more.

I've got this at the top:

```
x-dev-volumes: &dev-volumes
 volumes:
 - /root/keys:/var/run/keys:z
 - /root/vltpwd:/var/run/vltpwd:z
 - /root/config.ini:/var/run/config.ini:z
 - ./inventory:/runner/inventory:z
 - ./group_vars:/runner/playbooks/group_vars:z
 - ./host_vars:/runner/playbooks/host_vars:z
```

and then this later on.

```
 <<: *dev-volumes
 - ./build/playbooks:/runner/playbooks:z
```

and I'll have a different different sub-directory for playbooks.  Is there any way to use anchors, aliases, extensions, etc... to add something to a list or should I just give up and get WET (as opposed to DRY)?